# Заполнение массивов в структуре через указатели

Tags: c++, winapi

В WinMain'e я помещаю указатель на структуру в кармашек окна (setwindowlong), а в нем получаю этот указатель. И не могу понять, почему через указатель не получается заполнить массивы этой структуры - программа крашится - 121-122 строки.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>

#define Ellipsee 1
#define Rectanglee 2
#define SIZEX 4000
#define SIZEY 4000
#define RADIUS 25
#define COUNT 1000

LRESULT CALLBACK windowprocessforwindow(HWND handleforwindow, UINT message, 
WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);


struct FigurePP
{
int flag;
int X[COUNT];
int Y[COUNT];
};

void czCreateMenu(HWND handleforwindow1)
{
HMENU MainMenu = CreateMenu();
HMENU hPopupMenu = CreatePopupMenu();

AppendMenu(MainMenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT)hPopupMenu, "&Фигура");
{

    AppendMenu(hPopupMenu, MF_STRING, Ellipsee, "Круг");
    AppendMenu(hPopupMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, 1000, "");
    AppendMenu(hPopupMenu, MF_STRING, Rectanglee, "Прямоугольник");

    SetMenu(handleforwindow1, MainMenu);
    CheckMenuItem(hPopupMenu, Ellipsee, MF_CHECKED);
    EnableMenuItem(hPopupMenu, Ellipsee, MF_DISABLED | MF_GRAYED | MF_CHECKED);
}
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpCmdLine, 
int nShowCmd)
{


WNDCLASSEX windowclassforwindow1 = { 0 };
windowclassforwindow1.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
windowclassforwindow1.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
windowclassforwindow1.hInstance = hInst;
windowclassforwindow1.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
windowclassforwindow1.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)windowprocessforwindow;
windowclassforwindow1.lpszClassName = "windowclass 1";
windowclassforwindow1.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;

if (!RegisterClassEx(&windowclassforwindow1))
{

    MessageBox(NULL,
        "Window class creation failed",
        "Window Class Failed",
        MB_ICONERROR);
}

HWND handleforwindow = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
    windowclassforwindow1.lpszClassName,
    "Parent Window",
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL,
    350,
    250,
    640,
    480,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    hInst,
    NULL
);




if (!handleforwindow)
{


    MessageBox(NULL,
        "Window creation failed",
        "Window Creation Failed",
        MB_ICONERROR);
}

FigurePP figure;
figure.flag = Ellipsee;
SetWindowLong(handleforwindow, GWL_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)&figure);

ShowWindow(handleforwindow, nShowCmd);
czCreateMenu(handleforwindow);

MSG msg = { 0 };
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) != 0)
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}

return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK windowprocessforwindow(HWND handleforwindow, UINT uMsg, 
WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
//static int X[COUNT];
//static int Y[COUNT];

FigurePP* p = (FigurePP*)GetWindowLong(handleforwindow, GWL_USERDATA);

switch (uMsg)
{
case WM_CREATE:
{
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));


    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
    {
        p->X[i] = (int)(100 * rand() % SIZEX);
        p->Y[i] = (int)(100 * rand() % SIZEY);
    }
    return 0;
}

case WM_SIZE:
{
    static RECT rect = { 0L };

    GetClientRect(handleforwindow, &rect);

    SCROLLINFO sinfoo1;
    sinfoo1.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
    sinfoo1.fMask = SIF_RANGE | SIF_PAGE;
    sinfoo1.nMin = 0;
    sinfoo1.nMax = SIZEX - rect.right;
    sinfoo1.nPage = HIWORD(lParam);
    SetScrollInfo(handleforwindow, SB_HORZ, &sinfoo1, TRUE);

    SCROLLINFO sinfoo2;
    sinfoo2.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
    sinfoo2.fMask = SIF_RANGE | SIF_PAGE;
    sinfoo2.nMin = 0;
    sinfoo2.nMax = SIZEY - rect.bottom;
    sinfoo2.nPage = HIWORD(lParam);
    SetScrollInfo(handleforwindow, SB_VERT, &sinfoo2, TRUE);

    InvalidateRect(handleforwindow, NULL, true);

    break;
}
case WM_PAINT:
{
    int i;
    SCROLLINFO hscroll = { 0 }, vscroll = { 0 };
    hscroll.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
    hscroll.fMask = SIF_POS;
    GetScrollInfo(handleforwindow, SB_HORZ, &hscroll);

    vscroll.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
    vscroll.fMask = SIF_POS;
    GetScrollInfo(handleforwindow, SB_VERT, &vscroll);

    RECT scRect, Rect;
    PAINTSTRUCT Paint;

    GetClientRect(handleforwindow, &Rect);

    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(handleforwindow, &Paint);
    HBRUSH NewBrush1 = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 0));
    HBRUSH NewBrush2 = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 255, 255));
    HGDIOBJ OldBrush = SelectObject(hdc, NewBrush1);






    switch (p->flag)
    {
    case (Ellipsee):
    {
        for (i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
        {
            scRect.right = p->X[i] + RADIUS;
            scRect.left = p->X[i] - RADIUS;
            scRect.top = p->Y[i] - RADIUS;
            scRect.bottom = p->Y[i] + RADIUS;


            SelectObject(hdc, OldBrush);
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                SelectObject(hdc, NewBrush1);
            }
            else
            {
                SelectObject(hdc, NewBrush2);
            }
            if ((p->X[i] < Paint.rcPaint.right + 25 + hscroll.nPos && p->Y[i] > vscroll.nPos - 25) && (p->X[i] > hscroll.nPos - 25 && p->Y[i] < Paint.rcPaint.bottom + vscroll.nPos + 25))
            {
                Ellipse(hdc, p->X[i] - RADIUS - hscroll.nPos, p->Y[i] - RADIUS - vscroll.nPos, p->X[i] + RADIUS - hscroll.nPos, p->Y[i] + RADIUS - vscroll.nPos);
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    case (Rectanglee):
    {
        for (i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
        {
            scRect.right = p->X[i] + RADIUS;
            scRect.left = p->X[i] - RADIUS;
            scRect.top = p->Y[i] - RADIUS;
            scRect.bottom = p->Y[i] + RADIUS;


            SelectObject(hdc, OldBrush);
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                SelectObject(hdc, NewBrush1);
            }
            else
            {
                SelectObject(hdc, NewBrush2);
            }
            if ((p->X[i] < Paint.rcPaint.right + 25 + hscroll.nPos && p->Y[i] > vscroll.nPos - 25) && (p->X[i] > hscroll.nPos - 25 && p->Y[i] < Paint.rcPaint.bottom + vscroll.nPos + 25))
            {
                Rectangle(hdc, p->X[i] - RADIUS - hscroll.nPos, p->Y[i] - RADIUS - vscroll.nPos, p->X[i] + RADIUS - hscroll.nPos, p->Y[i] + RADIUS - vscroll.nPos);
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    }

    SelectObject(hdc, OldBrush);
    DeleteObject(NewBrush1);
    DeleteObject(NewBrush2);

    EndPaint(handleforwindow, &Paint);
    return 0;
}

case WM_HSCROLL:
{
    SCROLLINFO hscr;
    hscr.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
    hscr.fMask = SIF_ALL;

    GetScrollInfo(handleforwindow, SB_HORZ, &hscr);

    int min = hscr.nMin;
    int max = hscr.nMax;
    int ncurPos = hscr.nPos;
    int fpos = ncurPos;

    RECT rect;
    GetClientRect(handleforwindow, &rect);


    switch (LOWORD(wParam))
    {
    case SB_THUMBTRACK:
    {
        ncurPos = HIWORD(wParam);
        break;
    }
    case SB_LINERIGHT:
    {
        if (ncurPos < max - 200)
            ncurPos += 200;
        break;
    }
    case SB_PAGERIGHT:
    {
        if (ncurPos < max - 200)
        {
            ncurPos += 200;
        }
        else
            ncurPos = max;
        break;
    }
    case SB_LINELEFT:
    {
        if (ncurPos >(min + 200))
        {
            ncurPos -= 200;
        }
        else
        {
            ncurPos = min;
        }
        break;
    }
    case SB_PAGELEFT:
    {
        if (ncurPos > min + 200)
        {
            ncurPos -= 200;
        }
        else
            ncurPos = min;
        break;
    }
    }

    if (fpos != ncurPos)
    {
        SetScrollPos(handleforwindow, SB_HORZ, ncurPos, TRUE);
        ScrollWindow(handleforwindow, (fpos - ncurPos), 0, NULL, NULL);

        if (fpos - ncurPos < 0)
        {
            rect.left = rect.right + (fpos - ncurPos);
            InvalidateRect(handleforwindow, &rect, FALSE);
        }
        else
        {
            rect.right = rect.left + (fpos - ncurPos);
            InvalidateRect(handleforwindow, &rect, FALSE);
        }
    }
    break;
}


case WM_VSCROLL:
{
    SCROLLINFO vscr;
    vscr.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
    vscr.fMask = SIF_ALL;

    GetScrollInfo(handleforwindow, SB_VERT, &vscr);

    int min = vscr.nMin;
    int max = vscr.nMax;
    int ncurPos = vscr.nPos;
    int fpos = ncurPos;

    RECT rect;
    GetClientRect(handleforwindow, &rect);


    switch (LOWORD(wParam)) {
    case SB_THUMBTRACK:
    {
        ncurPos = vscr.nTrackPos;
        break;
    }
    case SB_LINEUP:
    {
        if (ncurPos > min + 200)
            ncurPos -= 200;
        else
            ncurPos = min;
        break;
    }
    case SB_LINEDOWN:
    {
        if (ncurPos < max - 200)
        {
            ncurPos += 200;
        }
        else
        {
            ncurPos = max;
        }
        break;
    }
    case SB_PAGEUP:
    {
        if (ncurPos > min)
        {
            ncurPos -= 400;
        }
        else ncurPos = min;
    }
    case SB_PAGEDOWN:
    {
        if (ncurPos < (max - 200))
        {
            ncurPos += 200;
        }
        else
        {
            ncurPos = max;
        }
    }
    }

    if (fpos != ncurPos)
    {
        SetScrollPos(handleforwindow, SB_VERT, ncurPos, TRUE);
        ScrollWindow(handleforwindow, 0, (fpos - ncurPos), NULL, NULL);

        if (fpos - ncurPos < 0)
        {
            rect.bottom = rect.top - (fpos - ncurPos);
            InvalidateRect(handleforwindow, &rect, true);
        }
        else
        {
            rect.top = rect.bottom - (fpos - ncurPos);
            InvalidateRect(handleforwindow, &rect, true);
        }
    }
    break;
}


case WM_DESTROY:
{
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    return 0;
}


case WM_COMMAND:
{

    HMENU hMenuBar = GetMenu(handleforwindow);

    switch (LOWORD(wParam))
    {
    case Ellipsee:
    {
        CheckMenuItem(GetSubMenu(hMenuBar, 0), Ellipsee, MF_CHECKED);
        EnableMenuItem(GetSubMenu(hMenuBar, 0), Ellipsee, MF_CHECKED | MF_DISABLED | MF_GRAYED);
        CheckMenuItem(GetSubMenu(hMenuBar, 0), Rectanglee, MF_UNCHECKED);
        EnableMenuItem(GetSubMenu(hMenuBar, 0), Rectanglee, MF_CHECKED);
        p->flag = Ellipsee;
        InvalidateRect(handleforwindow, NULL, true);
        break;
    }

    case Rectanglee:
    {
        CheckMenuItem(GetSubMenu(hMenuBar, 0), Ellipsee, MF_UNCHECKED);
        EnableMenuItem(GetSubMenu(hMenuBar, 0), Ellipsee, MF_CHECKED);
        CheckMenuItem(GetSubMenu(hMenuBar, 0), Rectanglee, MF_CHECKED);
        EnableMenuItem(GetSubMenu(hMenuBar, 0), Rectanglee, MF_CHECKED | MF_DISABLED | MF_GRAYED);
        p->flag = Rectanglee;
        InvalidateRect(handleforwindow, NULL, true);
        break;
    }
    }
}



}

return DefWindowProc(handleforwindow, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: в WM_CREATE не заполняются массивы через указатель.

Comment: Рискну предположить что WM_CREATE обрабатывается ДО вызова SetWindowLong

Comment: Ну, по логике, как я думал, после функции CreateWindow в кармашке уже лежит указатель, и в WM_CREATE уже можно заполнять массивы.

Comment: По какой логике код, написанный ниже должен выполниться раньше кода, написанного выше?

Comment: так в колбек функции мы получаем этот указатель - FigurePP* p и потом wm_create идет вроде

Comment: Берете отладчик, ставите бряк на WM_CREATE в windowprocessforwindow и на SetWindowLong. Отпускаете программу, смотрите что вызвалось раньше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Следует использовать функции `SetWindowLongPtr` и `GetWindowLongPtr`. При использовании `SetWindowLong` и `GetWindowLong` указатель может обрезаться, соответственно его разименование приводит к неопределенному поведению. Кроме того, после получаения указателя от `GetWindowLongPtr` его следует проверять на равенство нулю прежде чем разименовывать.

Так как сообщение `WM_CREATE` отправляется до того, как `CreateWindowEx` возвращется, то `SetWindowLongPtr` еще в этот момент не вызывалась, а вызов `GetWindowLongPtr` вернет 0. Однако `LPARAM` при этом будет содержать значение, переданное как последний параметр в `CreateWindowEx`. Соответственно чтобы все заработало надо передать нужный указатель в `CreateWindowEx`, а в обработчике `WM_CREATE` достать его из `LPARAM` и сохранить посредством `SetWindowLongPtr` для последующих вызовов:

```
FigurePP figure;
figure.flag = Ellipsee;

HWND handleforwindow = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
    windowclassforwindow1.lpszClassName,
    "Parent Window",
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VSCROLL | WS_HSCROLL,
    350,
    250,
    640,
    480,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    hInst,
    reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&figure)
);
```

...

```
LRESULT CALLBACK windowprocessforwindow(HWND handleforwindow, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    FigurePP * p = reinterpret_cast<FigurePP *>
    (
        GetWindowLongPtr(handleforwindow, GWL_USERDATA)
    );
    assert((nullptr != p) || (WM_CREATE == uMsg));
    switch(uMsg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            p = reinterpret_cast<FigurePP *>(lParam);
            assert(nullptr != p)
            SetWindowLongPtr(handleforwindow, GWL_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(p));
```

Comment: Попробовал - то же самое получается.

Comment: @Alexander И что, при первом вызове `windowprocessforwindow` `GetWindowLong` возвращает не нулевое значение?

Comment: Ну я подебажил, в указатель приходит значение 0x00000000 <NULL>

Comment: @Alexander Обновил ответ.