# Определить какая кнопка зажата (стиль)

Tags: c++, winapi

Есть, например, 200 кнопок (обычная и radiobutton).

```
button[i]=  CreateWindow(
            TEXT("BUTTON"),  // Predefined class; Unicode assumed 
            strBtn,      // Button text 
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,  // Styles 
            10,         // x position 
            ypos,         // y position 
            120,        // Button width
            30,        // Button height
            hWnd,     // Parent window
            HMENU(i),       // No menu.
            hInst,
            NULL);


       radiobutton[i] = CreateWindow(
            TEXT("BUTTON"),  // Predefined class; Unicode assumed 
            strBtn,      // Button text 
            WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON,  // Styles 
            160,         // x position 
            ypos,         // y position 
            110,        // Button width
            30,        // Button height
            hWnd,     // Parent window
            HMENU(i),       // No menu.
            hInst,
            NULL);
```

В WM_COMMAND я хочу сделать следующее - если нажать на i-тую обычную кнопку, то вместе с ней нажимается i-ая radiobutton, а предыдущие отжимаются. И наоборот, если нажать на i-ую радиокнопку, нажимается и i-ая обычная кнопка. Но у меня работает коряво, видимо не определяю какая кнопка нажата?

```
case WM_COMMAND:
{
    switch (LOWORD(wParam))
    {
    default:
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < BUTTONCOUNT; i++)
        {
            Button_SetCheck(radiobutton[i], BST_UNCHECKED);
            Button_SetState(button[i], FALSE);
        }
        Button_SetCheck(radiobutton[LOWORD(wParam)], BST_CHECKED);
        Button_SetState(button[LOWORD(wParam)], TRUE);
    }
    }//коряво

    break;
}
```

Comment: Это смахивает на дубликат [Сделать предыдущую кнопку не нажатой (не выпуклой)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/740321/Сделать-предыдущую-кнопку-не-нажатой-не-выпуклой/740365#740365). Вы там из одного заведения что ли?

Comment: Может быть. Я не знаю.

Comment: И спасибо за ссылку на тему.